# wix toolset detect 32bit / 64bit system

Tags: variables, x86, wix, 64-bit, preprocessor

I want my installer to be able to detect if the operating system runs under 32 bit or under 64 bit.
I am using Wix Toolset for Visual Studio 2017.
I tried these ...

```
  <?if $(sys.BUILDARCH) = "x64" ?>
  <?if $(var.Platform) = "x64" ?>  
  <?ifdef $(VersionNT64) ?>
     ...
```

I know there are a some questions concerning this, but nothing worked.

There are preprocessor variables starting with different prefixes .var, .sys, .fun and .env.
Its explained what the perfixes mean, but I could not find any lists showing which variables there are...

Comment: Preprocessor directives like this are for build/compile time. Do you want conditions based on the build time OS or the run time OS (the os where you are installing the installer)?

Comment: I should have continued my research before asking the question here, for now I found the following facts somewhere : It seems to be a restriction of Windows Installer, that he is not able to install on X64 or on x86 using the same msi-file. There must be a msi for x64 and one for x86.
So I will set the actual system hardcoded.
But I still would be very happy to get to know where the variables, I mentioned above, are.

Comment: @Brian Sutherland  Thanks, it would have been the run time system I was interested in, but if I have to make two msi's for the 2 systems, I will hardcode the system.